# Clearing one element instead all elements from left in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have this unordered list:

```
<ul>
   <li>Element 1
      <ul>
         <li>teste</li>
         <li>teste</li>
         <li>teste</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li>Element 2
      <ul>
         <li>teste</li>
         <li>teste</li>
         <li>teste</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li>Element 3
      <ul>
         <li>teste</li>
         <li>teste</li>
         <li>teste</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li>Element 4
      <ul>
         <li>teste</li>
         <li>teste</li>
         <li>teste</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

and the style:

```
li {float: left; list-style: none;}
li ul li { float: none}
```

I'll like to clear: left only the Element 3 in this unordered list. I think this will be more like this:

```
Element 1   Element 2   Element 4
teste       teste       teste
teste       teste       teste
teste       teste       teste

            Element 3
            teste
            teste
            teste
```

Its this possible? With clear: left?

Comment: No, with just clear:left it is not possible

Comment: I'm tryed to make the Element 3 with negative margin, but im not a fan to negative margins. Any thoughts?

Comment: This is a solution but I don't know if it will be feasible for you: http://jsfiddle.net/xeh1dbzn/3/.

Comment: why are you messing with ul / li?

Comment: @FahadHasan my opinion is to post it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this: http://jsfiddle.net/xeh1dbzn/3/. I switched the 4th `<li>` with the 3rd `<li>` and this is the CSS:

```
ul {
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}
li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
ul li ul li {
    display: block;
}
ul li:nth-child(4) {
    display: block;
}
```